# Does Stack Overflow ever get spammed?

Tags: discussion, spam

I know that Stack Overflow (and, for that matter, the entire Stack Exchange network) are tightly moderated by CAPTCHAs, admins, and users, but on a network this size it's hard to believe that spam should never get through.

Has spam ever gotten through, or made it to the homepage (even if only to be deleted soon afterwards)?

Comment: Spammers try all the time, and get beaten down pretty quickly. Only *questions* are posted to the homepage, and that means they get more attention even than answers. Any such spam lasts microseconds before being closed and deleted.

Comment: There are so many eyes that spam doesn't survive long usually. Six spam flags and it's gone, or if a moderator is faster, one moderator suffices.

Comment: I see a spam post every couple of weeks. It's usually gone before I can even flag them.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is probably "yes", but it's hard to say for certain.

Spam gets flagged and removed very quickly around here, and I bet at least some of those flags come from people seeing it on the front page.

Comment: Front page, and review queues.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe Oh yeah, especially with the new /review implementation.

Comment: Yup, makes a great honeypot candidate.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

SPAM...PLEASE DELETE ME LATER.

Comment: Would it be helpful to flag this post?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, no this spam is kept here as an example for the rest.

Comment: We are, after all, trying to answer the question. WITH SCIENCE.

Comment: @TimYiJiang Look at me still commenting when there's science to do...